# How to count number of API calls in a Google API based web application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have come across a Web application based on Java, JavaScript and JQuery. I need to report how many API calls are made by the application to the Google servers for showing the data on Map.

I am new to google maps. While going through the code, I find `google.maps` constructor being called at multiple location. Ex-

`new google.maps.Marker`, `new google.maps.geocoder` and so on.

I am confused whether all such instances with `new` keyword are all API calls interchanging data or they are method calls within the scripts.

Is there any way to find out exact amount of API calls being made. Basically my motive is to report API calls which charge cost.

Comment: You can use variable and each time you call API just do `apiCalls++`

Answer (score 1):

I recently used this API Console to calculate Google Maps JavaScript API calls. You can use it for a bunch of different Google APIs.

Google API Console:

https://console.developers.google.com/

Refer docs at:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project

Hope, it's helpful.